# C: Reading a whole file into buffer and byteswap the buf | ADDECEFA -> DEADFACE

Tags: c, performance, buffer, byte-shifting

EDIT: After doing some more research, it seems that what i actually need is big endian to middle endian and vice versa. so 12345678 -> 34127856 and back. Sorry for any confusion.

I have a small file, exactly 16MB. I am reading the whole file into a buffer. What Im trying to do is byteswap the whole file/buffer in one go if possible (eg. uniformly/globaly swaps ADDECEFA => DEADFACE). I have read countless pages of byteswapping but alot of the bitwise/byteswap stuff goes right over my head for some reason (dumb brain most likely). If anyone knows a bitwise/byteswap for dummies, please point me in the right direction!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    const char * suffix = ".reversed";

    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    char * out = strcat(argv[1], suffix);
    FILE *output = fopen(out, "wb");

    int data[16384];
    int swapped;

 while(fread(data,sizeof data, 1, input)){

    swapped = ((data & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
              ((data & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |
              ((data & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) |
              ((data & 0xFF000000) >> 24);

    fwrite(swapped, sizeof data , 1, output);

            /*  by golly it copies the file fast as heck!
                but i am unsure how to manipulate 'data' buffer
                so as it uniformly/globaly swaps ADDECEFA => DEADFACE 
            */
        }
    }
```

Also, if you see me doing something wrong in my code, please tell me and show me a better way. If you need me to elaborate anything please dont hesitate to ask. Thanks and have a good one.

EDIT: I added one of my failed attempts. My end goal was to swap the bytes as I write it back out to outfile and swap them as efficiently as possible.

Comment: It is too dangerous to `strcat(argv[1], suffix);` you have no idea if there is enough room.

Comment: hmm so what would be the best way to handle that? I looked for a way to add the suffix to the filename from argv. ofcourse argv[1]+".suffix" didnt work ;(

Comment: i guess i could output a static filename then rename it after im done.

Comment: i did find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119718/appending-string-to-input-file-name-in-c"

Comment: Allocate memory with the required space (incl `'\0'` terminator) and build a new string. Either with `strcpy` and `strcat`, or with `sprintf`. But do please check `argc` before accessing `argv[]`. Please show how you have tried to do the swapping. From the example, it looks as if you want to swap each pair of bytes.

Comment: I tried alot of different things, i would go back and edit my code to include all of the resources but it would take me a while to find them all. let me see what i can do. Everything i tried either crashed, or didnt work. I really want to swap the largest amount of bytes possible, I realize the swapping 4 or 8 pair of bytes would be faster than swapping one pair of bytes. Ill put one of the failed attempts of byteswapping up in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
int data[16384];
```

this code

```
while(fread(data,sizeof data, 1, input)){
```

will try to read 16,384 `int` values from `input`.  Nothing wrong so far.

But this code:

```
swapped = ((data & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
          ((data & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |
          ((data & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) |
          ((data & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

Will put try to stuff whatever part that fits of the byte-swapped *address* of `data` into `swapped`, because `data` is evaluated as the address of the first element of the array.

You probably want something like this:

```
swapped = ((data[ 0 ] & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
          ((data[ 0 ] & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |
          ((data[ 0 ] & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) |
          ((data[ 0 ] & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

But that has a problem that shifting *signed* `int` values has implementation-defined behavior.  See [Arithmetic bit-shift on a signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009885/arithmetic-bit-shift-on-a-signed-integer)

So you probably want

```
unsigned int data[16384];
```

Even given that, though, you're only swapping one `int` value.  You need to loop over all the data that's been read, swapping each `int`, assuming that's what you want to do.

Which raises another problem - your code does not track how much data it needs to byte swap.  You need to count the number of `int` values read in and *use* that.

Finally, this code

```
fwrite(swapped, sizeof data , 1, output);
```

will write `sizeof data` bytes to `output`, starting at the address of whatever `swapped` happens to point to.  But this is the definition of `swapped`:

```
int swapped;
```

So that `fwrite()` call is undefined behavior.

Comment: "But this is the definition of swapped" hmm i thought that i added to swapped when i tried to byteswap data. I think i see what you mean though, i should have did 'sizeof swapped' right?

Comment: @james28909 - assuming you mean the `fwrite()` statement, it should probably be something like `fwrite( &swapped, sizeof swapped, 1, output );`  Note that the first argument to `fwrite()` is the *address* of the data to be written.

Comment: i do appreciate your comments, so thanks for that. but i am going to put this down for the evening and pick it back up tomorrow. thanks for your help